Почему Stack Overflow так называется?
Мне вдруг стало интересно почему Stack Overflow так называется и чём смысл этого названия?
Вы можете либо согласиться с моей гипотезой, либо, если моя гипотеза не верна написать истинную причину.
Моя Гипотеза

Название Stack Overflow было выбрано в каком-то голосовании, а смысла большого у этого названия нету.


Вопрос задавали в enSO: Why was "Stack Overflow" chosen as a name for this site?
Название действительно было выбрано на голосовании. Вариант Stack Overflow победил с 25% голосов.
Джефф Этвуд (сооснователь SO), как он сам пишет в блоге, придумал данное название в ходе мозгового штурма, и оно было одним из нескольких возможных. Мы не можем знать, что происходило у другого человека тогда в голове. Но сообществу понравилось в обсуждении следующее объяснение, почему люди могли выбрать именно Stack Overflow:

Некоторые (многие) (большинство?) CPU реализуют "стек", который
представляет собой область памяти, используемую для хранения
аргументов процедур, переменных и возвращаемых значений функций. Эта
область памяти ограничена по размеру, и когда программа пытается
использовать больше стека, чем доступно, возникает ошибка
"переполнения стека". Таким образом, название сайта Stack Overflow -
это своего рода программистский юмор, указывающий на то, что именно
сюда могут обратиться программисты, когда их стек переполнен, или,
другими словами, когда у них заканчиваются идеи и им нужна помощь.

